# How to disable routing all traffic (including web-traffic) through the VPN in client's .ovpn config file?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-14.04

In order to connect to corporate network I've got these four files

- ca.crt
- client.ovpn
- client.key
- client.crt

I couldn't create VPN connection via Ubuntu GUI, but I managed to get it work from command line by `cd` into folder with these files and `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn`. It connects me to network but I can't access any other host outside the network. After a lot of f googling it seems that because routing of all my traffic (including web-traffic) through the VPN is enabled. On forums people suggest to check the checkbox `Use this connection only for resources on its network` in VPN editing window. But since I couldn't create connection via GUI -  I don't have it in the list of connections and hence I can't edit it anyhow via GUI. But maybe I can add something into my client.ovpn config file to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

### Answer 1

In the OpenVPN client file `client.ovpn` find and comment out this line if it exists:

```
redirect-gateway
# This is a comment so change line above to this
# redirect-gateway
```

If the admin or server hasn't put this in the client file or is "pushing" redirect-gateway, you can manually override it following these instructions: [IgnoreRedirectGateway](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway).

To help determime how best to proceed, do the following.  First reset everything to how things were before vpn (e.g. reboot).  Then check you can access local network. Then run:

```
sudo ip route
```

This will show **current** default gateway - make a note of this, we'll call it `original`. Then run vpn client as normal `sudo openvpn config.opvn`. Once connection established, run `sudo ip route`.  You should see default gateway has changed, hence everything is being routed through VPN.

Next kill openvpn and run `sudo ip route` again to check settings have been restored.  Then run client with `--route-nopull` option as it:

> `--route-nopull` 
>    for routes and dhcp options like DNS servers. 
>    When used on the client, this option effectively bars the server from adding routes to the client's routing table, however note that this option still allows the server to set the TCP/IP properties of the client's TUN/TAP interface.

Finally check using `sudo ip route` that the default gateway is the same as the `original` (as that's what the command does).  You should in theory have local net access and a vpn interface.

Method 2 essentially accepts the full VPN config but then allows you to manually specify the gateway address.

### Answer 2

Have you tried this already? [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/establish-openvpn-connection-ubuntu-1404/)

Comment: I don't have this line in my client.ovpn, so I tried to run `sudo openvpn --route-noexec --config client.ovpn`  and `sudo openvpn --route-nopull --config client.ovpn`. After both these commands I couldn't reach nor inner network resources nor outer Internet ones. And moreover now when I run `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn` I can't connect to anything at all. What have I done?

Comment: When you closed or killed the openvpn client it should've restored your default gateway (i.e. it should behave as it did before running the program).  Do the following, restart PC and check if you can access the internet etc.  There should be no permanent effects if running from command line.

Comment: You need to check that in between running openvpn, the system restored your original network config.

Comment: I'm afraid I already tried rebooting and it didn't help.

Comment: Is the VPN still running?

Comment: couldn't follow steps shown in [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/05/establish-openvpn-connection-ubuntu-1404/) (you can actually see my comment on that matter it's the latest comment so far - **Dmitriy May 15, 2015 at 6:34 am** )

Comment: Please post output of `sudo ifconfig` `sudo ip route`

Comment: No, it isn't. When I try to connect to it, I loose internet connection.

Comment: sudo: ipconfig: command not found

Comment: On Linux it's `sudo ifconfig` and NOT IP

Comment: and output of sudo ip route: default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.96  metric 9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23800/discussion-between-dkab-and-fswings).

Comment: It's best to add these details to your question otherwise it makes it tricky to see it in the comments.